# Missing xfeatures2d.hpp in opencv2 folder?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv3.0, sift, cmake-gui

I just installed via cmake (OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULS_PATH) and mingw530 (Qt)

- opencv-3.4.2
- opencv_contrib-3.4.2
- mingw32-make
- mingw32-make install

Filestructur is

- opencv/source
- opencv/build
- opencv/release (compile folder)
- opencv/contrib

But if I try to insert

#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"

it does not find it.

The same problem is already descript here:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/57397/cant-find-xfeatures2dhpp/

But I don't understand the solution
**"@Bhatt, on win, you will have to build the INSTALL project. this will copy headers/libs/dlls to your install folder"**.

My fallback is to insert

#include "E:/PROGRAMS/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.4.2/modules/xfeatures2d/include/opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp"

then it works. Can someone explain me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who is interested: The equivalent to VS+INSTALL project is mingw32-make install. The clue is the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in cmake where this files (headers/libs/dlls) are saved. Add to your Qt .pro file INCLUDEPATH += \install\include.